# Write descriptions to a database - UTF8 - Escape?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, utf-8, escaping

I want to write the  values of [this XML file](http://j-trier.de/cronjob/data/gamesplanet.xml) to my database. My problem is, that I get a SQL error every time, I want to add those descriptions. I already tried to escape special characters by using `preg_quote` but it doesn't work...

But I do not know why it isn't working. This function adds the values into my database:

```
function addToSQL($dom, $XMLpath, $shopID){
    $doc = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    $items = $doc->xpath($XMLpath);
    $database = new mysqli("localhost", "censored", "censored", "censored");
    $sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO `wp_all_import_xml` (name, price, price_old, shop, url, publisher, category, platform, picture, description) VALUES \n";

    echo "(addToSQL) Transferring Data into SQL\n";

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($item);
        $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
        $price = $node->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0)->textContent;
        $url = $node->getElementsByTagName('url')->item(0)->textContent;
        $price_old = 0;
        $publisher = "";
        $category = "";
        $platform = "";
        $image = "";
        $description = "";

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('price_base')->item(0)){
            $publisher = $node->getElementsByTagName('price_base')->item(0)->textContent;
        }

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)){
            $publisher = $node->getElementsByTagName('publisher')->item(0)->textContent;
        }

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)){
            $category = $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->textContent;
        }

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('platform')->item(0)){
            $platform = $node->getElementsByTagName('platform')->item(0)->textContent;
        }

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0)){
            $image = $node->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0)->textContent;
        }

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('packshot')->item(0)){
            $image = $node->getElementsByTagName('packshot')->item(0)->textContent;
        }

        if($node->getElementsByTagName('desc')->item(0)){
            $description = $node->getElementsByTagName('desc')->item(0)->textContent;
            //$description = preg_quote($description);
            //echo $description . "\n";
        }

        $sqlstatement .= "('$title', '$price', '$price_old', '$shopID', '$url', '$publisher', '$category', '$platform', '$image', '$description')," . "\n";
    }

    $sqlstatement = substr($sqlstatement, 0, -2) . ";";
    //$sqlstatement = $database->real_escape_string($sqlstatement);

    if(!(($database->query($sqlstatement))  === TRUE)){
        echo "(addToSQL) Error writing games to database!\n";
    }

    $sqlstatement = null;
    $sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO `wp_all_import_xml` (name, price, shop, url, publisher, category, platform, description) VALUES \n";

    echo "(addToSQL) finished\n";
}
```

This function works fine with all my other XML files because they do not contain descriptions. And because they do not contain descriptions, the var `$descriptions` is going to be `""` because the tag `desc` doesn't exists. This function has also worked with my XML file where I want to add the description to the database. But after I added this:

```
if($node->getElementsByTagName('desc')->item(0)){
    $description = $node->getElementsByTagName('desc')->item(0)->textContent;
    //$description = preg_quote($description);
    //echo $description . "\n";
}
```

The SQL query for this XML file fails every time. So, it must be the description.

But how can I solve this? - What's wrong? - Where is my failure?
Do I have to tell the var `$description` to encode the string into UTF-8?

I do not have a idea anymore... Would be very happy about help!

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to use:

`$database->real_escape_string($parameter);`

for all your parameters that are to be inserted.
It should take care of any invalid characters as well as protect your database from any sql injections.

Comment: But this isn't solving the problem at all

Comment: @FrazeJr. -- Escape each item _before_ building the SQL string.  Please display `$sqlstatement` so you (and we) can see what the `INSERT` looks like.

Comment: Ok, it is working now. Thank You! But I have a question left. Why do I have now words in the database which looks like this: `EnthÃ¤l`. And in the XML file they look like this `Enthält `? - How can I solve that?

Comment: After:
`$database = new mysqli("localhost", "censored", "censored", "censored");`

try executing:
`$database->set_charset("utf8")`